# Validate the proof that the sequence $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} {1\over n+k}$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

> Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and:
>   $$
> x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} {1\over n+k}
> $$
>   Prove that $x_n$ is a bounded sequence.

I'm wondering whether the proof below is valid.

Since $n \in \mathbb N$ we have that $x_n$ is strictly greater than $0$. For the upper bound lets consider the following sequence $y_n$:

$$
\begin{align}
y_n &= {1 \over n + 1} + {1 \over n + 1} + \dots + {1 \over n + 1} = \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^n {1 \over n+1} = {n \over n + 1}
\end{align}
$$

Since $x_n$ has an increasing denominator in each consecutive term of the sum we may conclude that $x_n < y_n$. So summarizing the above:

$$
0 < x_n < y_n
$$

Which means that the sequence is bounded. Have I missed something?

Comment: Side-note: The sequence converges to $\ln 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):0<x_n<y_n$, but asserting that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded means that there are *constants* $a$ and $b$ such that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):a<x_n<b.$$That's easy, though, after what you did. Just take $a=0$ (of course) and $b=1$.

Answer (score 6):

$$ x_n \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+n}\sqrt{k+n-1}}\stackrel{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}{\leq}\sqrt{n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k+n-1}-\frac{1}{k+n}\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}. $$

Answer (score 1):

$x_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} {1\over n+k}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}{1\over 1+\frac{k}{n}}=\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{1\over 1+\frac{k}{n}}$ Riemann sum $=\int\limits_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}dx=\ln2$